# Loop through csv, write new values to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, loops, csv

**Introduction**

Since I worked with scrapy for the last two months, I made a break and started to learn text formatting with python.
I got some data delivered by my webcrawler, which are stored in a .csvFile, like you can see below:

**My .csvFile**

```
SKU
"
                Article nr. : 560821800 / D26 x H10 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560828100 / D14 x H11 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560821400 / D13 x H10 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560821900 / L17 x W17 x H14
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560828900 / L17 x W17 x H14
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560821600 / D16 x H13 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560828300 / D16 x H13 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560827900 / D13 x H10 cm
            "
"
                Article nr. : 560829000 / L17 x W17 x H14
            "
```

There are so many whitespaces and other things i dont want to have, so i read about "RegularExpression".

Now i played a bit around, and managed to delete all whitespace and others unwanted digits, so i only have f.e `560821800` which stands for the id's of specific products.

Now I opened the .csv file, edited the values and tried to write it to a new .csv file, which I called output.

The "Output"-file only contains one column, which i wanted to call "SKU".

**Code**

```py
import csv
import re
    
with open(r'C:\Users\y.y\OneDrive - company name\Python3_Textformatierung\sku.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        sku = row.pop()
        sku = re.sub(r'[\s\t\n]+|(\.)+|(\:)', '', sku)
        sku = sku.replace('Articlenr', '')
        print(sku)#string splitted to ['560827900', 'D13xH10cm']
        string_to_list = sku.split('/')#splits string to list
        print(string_to_list)
        sku_string = string_to_list.pop(0)
        print(sku_string)#only value of sku remains
```

After running this code i got following **output**:

```
SKU
['SKU']
SKU
560821800/D26xH10cm
['560821800', 'D26xH10cm']
560821800
560828100/D14xH11cm
['560828100', 'D14xH11cm']
560828100
560821400/D13xH10cm
['560821400', 'D13xH10cm']
560821400
560821900/L17xW17xH14
['560821900', 'L17xW17xH14']
560821900
560828900/L17xW17xH14
['560828900', 'L17xW17xH14']
560828900
560821600/D16xH13cm
['560821600', 'D16xH13cm']
560821600
560828300/D16xH13cm
['560828300', 'D16xH13cm']
560828300
560827900/D13xH10cm
['560827900', 'D13xH10cm']
560827900
560829000/L17xW17xH14
['560829000', 'L17xW17xH14']
560829000
```

**My Problem**
I want to collect every single value of `sku_string` and write them to the output.csv-File, but only the fieldname is passed to the new file.

I tried this task with following code:

```py
#write data to csv with fieldname['SKU']
with open(r'C:\Path\to\Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldname = ['SKU']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldname, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    print(sku_string)
    for s in row:
        csv_writer.writerow(['SKU', sku_string])
```

I also recognized, that the last print-statement i used(only for testing), it only holds one value, what am i missing?

*I'am real beginner, i read a lot about loops here on stackoverflow, but i couldnt transfer the solutions to my problem, because most of them were too high for my actual skill-level*

**Update**

I reworked my code, but it still writes only the last output to the Output.csv file ._.

```py
import csv
import re


with open(r'Path\to\sku.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row = row.pop()#convert from list to str        
        row = row.split('/')#convert str to list with 2 elements, splitted by '/'
        sku_string = row.pop(0)#string with Articlenr + SKU
        sku_string = sku_string.split(':')
        only_sku = sku_string.pop()
        #every string contains only sku now
        print(only_sku)     
        
with open(r'C:\Path\to\Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldname = ['SKU']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()
    for x in only_sku:
        writer.writerow({'SKU' : only_sku})
```

**Output.csv**

[image: output.csv]

Comment: Why are you using csvreader? Your file is not a csv or for that matter an <anything>-separated-value file.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Its the original output my crawler provided me. Why do you think, its not a csv file? Do you think pandas would be better than csvreader?

Comment: It's not a csv file because csv stands for comma-separated values, which means it's like an excel sheet except that the columns are separated by commas. A csv file with _one column_ is essentially just a regular file with one entry per line.

Comment: alright, i check it out it took some values out of my "real-csv" just to practice, but i never thought about it, that this could cause my error, thanks for that mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New values from each row are written to your `only_sku` string *inside the `for row in csv_reader:` loop*. If you want to access these values outside the loop, you will need to *collect them somewhere*, for example by append them to a list.

So your read loop becomes:

```
all_sku = []
with open(r'Path\to\sku.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row = row.pop()#convert from list to str        
        row = row.split('/')#convert str to list with 2 elements, splitted by '/'
        sku_string = row.pop(0)#string with Articlenr + SKU
        sku_string = sku_string.split(':')
        only_sku = sku_string.pop().strip()
        #every string contains only sku now
        print(only_sku)     
        all_sku.append(only_sku)
```

Notice how we add the latest value that we read to our list of all values using `all_sku.append()`. We also want to *strip* the leading and trailing whitespace from our values.

And then you can write in another loop like so:

```
with open(r'C:\Path\to\Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldname = ['SKU']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()
    for x in all_sku:
        writer.writerow({'SKU' : x})
```

Notice we now loop over `all_sku` and write each element of that list.

---

Now if you wanted the dimensions to also be written to your new csv file, you would need to keep track of that value too. Instead of creating a list of strings like we did earlier, it's easier to create a list of the `dict`s that we want to pass to `writer.writerow()` later. So we'd have:

```
all_rows = []
with open(r'Path\to\sku.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row = row.pop() #convert from list to str        
        row = row.split('/')#convert str to list with 2 elements, splitted by '/'
        sku_string = row[0]
        dims_string = row[1].strip()
        sku_string = sku_string.split(':')
        only_sku = sku_string[1].strip()
        all_sku.append({'SKU': only_sku, 'Dimensions': dims_string})
```

And then write like so:

```
with open(r'C:\Path\to\Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldname = ['SKU', 'Dimensions']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row_dict in all_rows:
        writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Comment: i also tried passing the values to a list before, but i didnt wrote it correctly in my loop. Thanks for all and g'day!

Answer (score 1):

I took a bit different approach and I've changed your `.csv` file to a `.txt` file as, honestly, whatever you have there doesn't look like CSV structure.

Here's what I came up with:

```
import csv

with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

parsed_lines = [l for l in [l.strip() for l in lines] if l != '"' and l != "SKU"]
parsed_lines = [l.replace("Article nr. : ", "").split("/") for l in parsed_lines]

with open("output.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["Article nr.", "Dimensions"])
    w.writerows(parsed_lines)
```

Output:

```
  Article nr.  Dimensions
-------------  ---------------
   560821800   D26 x H10 cm
   560828100   D14 x H11 cm
   560821400   D13 x H10 cm
   560821900   L17 x W17 x H14
   560828900   L17 x W17 x H14
   560821600   D16 x H13 cm
   560828300   D16 x H13 cm
   560827900   D13 x H10 cm
   560829000   L17 x W17 x H14
```

Or in the `.csv` file:

[image]

Comment: hey baduker, your suggestion also worked for me:) I never came up with the idea, that my csv is broken. Your solution is well done, but for my skill level at the moment a bit too high i guess :> your bio is funny, i feel bad now for not being able to checkmark you :(

Comment: @y.y glad it worked out. If this feels a bit overwhelming, take a look a Python's list comprehensions, [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) might explain a lot.

Comment: i definitely have to take a look at some python features in depth. have a nice day :)